# NSSortDescriptor get key from core data in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, sorting, core-data

I am new to IOs developement and core Data.

In my application I want to use NSSortDescriptor to sort Data before fetching it to my tableview.

In my core data I have one table "TBL_Products" with two fields "product_name" and "Quantity"

The code below work perfectly fine

```
let MySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "product_name" , ascending: true)
```

But what I hate about it is I am hard coding the key name so the app will crash if the column name has been changed.

Is there is a way do to something like this (the code below not working):

```
let MySortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: TBL_Products.product_name.descriptor , ascending: true)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use can use `#keyPath` directive:

```swift
NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(TBL_Products.product_name), ascending: true)
```

The compiler replaces that with a string containing the property name.
It is also useful in Core Data predicates, e.g.

```swift
NSPredicate(format: "%K == %@", #keyPath(TBL_Products.product_name), "someProduct")
```

Answer (score 5):

Note in Swift 5 this has been updated to use `\.` syntax instead of the `#keypath` directive:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: \TBL_Products.product_name, ascending: true)
```